# Is it possible to change an app icon depending on the market?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app published in the U.S and in several countries, including Japan. I'd like to change the icon in Japan. I couldn't find anything on iTunes related to this issue.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have different icons for the same app.

You will need to release two versions of your app - one in the Japanese store and one for all other territories.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paul, do you have any idea why Apple does this? It's very unpractical.

Comment: No idea, but the icon is baked into the app package, so I guess there may be some reason that they didn't want to make it localisable. Apple human interface guidelines recommend a graphical rather than textual icon so maybe they think it shouldn't need to be localised?

Comment: True, but graphicals also need to be localised :P what a shame. Maybe they'll change this later.